# How to use PowerShell Azure cmdlets to log into my Azure subscription and use `Get-AzureRmResource`

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-functions

In a PS console I can do the following to get all of the Azure resources for a subscription.

`Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmResource`

I want to do this in a Azure function, but `Login-AzureRmAccount` is an interactive prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to log in using a service principal instead of interactive login. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-authenticate-service-principal for details on setting that up.